# Chrome icon lost from panel

Tags: google-chrome, panel, gnome-panel

Here are the screen shots:

[image]

A zoom in of the bottom panel:

[image]

As you can see, on Ubuntu's the bottom panel, the chrome icon is missing, how can I get it back? I tried to completely remove chrome and re-install, no joy. I have also tried to delete all local .config/google-chrome folder files, still no joy.

Answer (score 4):

Just had this problem too and entered here looking for an answer and after being disappointed for not finding one I just wanted to search deeply into Chrome options and **got it!** :P look, go at Chrome, to Settings, and at the bottom, click for Advanced Settings and almost at the bottom (again), you'll find it as an unchecked box saying something like: "Run apps as a background process still while chrome is closed"... If you don't get something because of my bad explanation... or get stuck... or whatever, just tell me.
Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as [Daniel](https://askubuntu.com/users/67287/daniel), and investigated what [user224290](https://askubuntu.com/users/224290/user224290) suggested, but mine was already checked. Unchecking it fixed the issue and rechecking it did not destroy the fix. Opening the settings and changing anything might be enough to force chrome to refresh its settings and display the tray icon once again.

Comment: I had a similar issue - chrome apps were opening as normal chrome windows, and had disappeared from my launcher. The option you mentioned was already checked too, and the issue had had just started in the middle of a session. I unchecked the option, quit chrome, reopened and checked the option, restarted my computer and chrome apps were opening as their own windows again!